# Problems with namespaces and Call to undefined function in php

Tags: php, namespaces

Hi I am having a problem with my index.php whenever I go to http://localhost/blog/admin/index.php I get an error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function Blog\DB\connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\blog.php on line 6.  In admin folder I am requiring my blog.php.

index.php

```
<?php  
 require '../blog.php';
?>
```

Now in blog.php

```
<?php

     require 'functions.php';
     require 'db.php';

     $conn = Blog\DB\connect($config);
     if( !$conn )
     {
       die('couldnt connect to the database');
     }
```

Now In db.php

```
<?php namespace Blog\DB;

   require 'config.php';

   function connect($config)
   {    
     try{
          $conn = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blogs', 
          $config['DB_USERNAME'], 
          $config['DB_PASSWRORD']);
          $conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          return $conn;
         }
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
         return false;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Where's your index.php code?

Comment: blog.php is the index.php , sorry I am using stack over flow for the first time.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need to name blog.php as index.php for there to be an index to go to?

Comment: Yes I edited it but I really do not understand why does it say Call to undefined function connect() only in that admin directory.

Comment: You're calling the function wrong, get rid of the whole Blog\DB\ before connect($config) and include db.php.

Comment: But I have to use the namespace before it to call the connect() function as in db.php I have mentioned I want to use namespace Blog\DB;

Comment: if you are using namespace, why not also use class ??

Comment: But php thinks that you're trying to call the function Blog\DB\Connect($config) and not the function Connect($config). If you include db.php and call the function it will pick up on the fact that it's from the db.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, you need to have the global namespace like so

```
$conn = \Blog\DB\connect($config); // mind the \ before Blog
```

Or the function is simply not defined (`connect()` that is).

Comment: No I tried that I didnt work and sorry blog.php is the index.php.

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling the function you're calling a function from your blog.php not db.php indicated by the error. In order to solve this problem you have to include db.php (Which might already be included by the *require*) and then call the function normally e.g.

```
include db.php
$conn = connect($config)
```

Comment: I did the same thing but it doesnt work dont know why ?

Comment: No nothing @General Charismo